# Php curl auto authentication not setting the session

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I am using php curl function for auto authentication, and it works fine.But i am not able to go to another page on the same domain and I think session is not set.Help me please,thanks in advance.

Comment: provide some code please

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep session information, you will need to tell CURL where to store Cookie data. You can do this with the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options set with [curl_setopt](http://us.php.net/curl_setopt).

**EDIT** Here's an example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to send over the session cookie when going over to the other page to maintain state

See: [Maintaining PHP session when using CURL](http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/07/24/maintaining-php-session-when-using-curl/)

Comment: Not sure of why the downvote - something wrong with what I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

With curl and rest-services you don't have session. So, as a solution your auth operation should return session_id and you should pass that session_id in the next request where request is signed. After that you should implement additional security checks by session_id.

The best way to me is to integrate OAuth2 authentication when you have access_token, expired_in and refresh_token. Refresh_token is optional parameter and you can use it when you try to get new access_token by refresh_token when access_token is expired.